# lock a scrollviewer in place

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer, microsoft.ink

I have an inkpresenter inside a scrollviewer for a Windows Phone 7 application.  Often when the user starts to draw, the scrollviewer takes over mid stroke, making it hard to actually draw stuff.  I tried disabling the ScrollBarVisibility when the inkpresenter needs to be used, but then the scroll viewer automatically pans back up to the top.  So how can I prevent the scrollviewer from scrolling when the inkpresenter is in use, while still maintaining the scroll position?

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollBars" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding ScrollEnabled}" >
    <Canvas Height="2000">
        ...
        <InkPresenter Name="InkCanvas" Strokes="{Binding Strokes}" Canvas.Top="500" />
    </ Canvas >
</ScrollViewer >
```

---

Edit:

So I tried using the scrolling function in the codebehind to update the vertical offset, where I have a button linked to the following code:

```
var offset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
ScrollEnabled = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
```

Again, it just goes back up to the top.  Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that the value of the `offset` variable is not zero?

Comment: I check the offset in the debugger, it was a nonzero number.  Can "ScrollToVerticalOffset" be called when the scrollvarvisibility is disabled?

Comment: I thought it could be, but maybe I am wrong about that. Sorry my answer didn't work.

Comment: Could you try calling `Scrollviewer.UpdateLayout` after calling `Scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset`?

Comment: yeah I had tried that route as well... doesn't appear to be working.  Is there maybe an event to handle in the inkpresenter that I can handle the touch so it doesn't bubble up to the scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1):

After disabling the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` call `Scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset` to manually bring the InkPresenter into view.